# Single ecdsa signature valid for two different messages

Tags: dsa, message-recovery

I have been reading *Flaws in Applying Proof Methodologies to Signature Schemes* and ran into a bit I do not understand.

In *section 4.2* the authors describe a scheme where a malicious signer crafts a public key and signature that verifies two different messages. They postulate that upon revealing the second message the private key is exposed. I do not understand how that follows since both signature $s$ values are the same and thus cancel out when trying to recover the private key or nonce.

Could you guys enlighten me on that?

So to give a bit more detail.

The verification part is clear, the doctored private key reduces the equation to $-1 \times k\times G$ thus Giving us point $-R$ which has the same $x4 coordinate or $r$, while $y$ coordinate differs in sign.

The part that puzzles me is how a third party recovers the private key once the second signature hash is released.

From the nonce reuse, the formula is $k=(H(m_1)-H(m_2))/(s_1 - s_2)$ and since $s_1==s_2$ this computation fails since 0 does not have an inverse.

Comment: Could you provide the link and where did you exactly fail? You are talking about two different problems.

Comment: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/221355164_Flaws_in_Applying_Proof_Methodologies_to_Signature_Schemes

Comment: Section 4.2, they talk about the private key being revealed when second message is published. But I can not confirm that with math, since s values are the same trying to recover the private key ends up in trying to find an inverse of zero.

Comment: Look at how the $r$ is formed. The key is there,

Comment: From what I can see r is formed by selecting a nonce at random and computing k×G and taking the x coordinate as r. It is the private key that is doctored to be -(H(m1)+H(m2))/2r

Comment: @kelelaka got it, thank you.

Comment: The vulnerability is not in math of ECDSA itself. Read the title of paper and read it properly to understand what ‘flaws’ meant in that paper and what is the topic being discussed there.

Comment: @madhurkant from what I understood of the paper it rougly postulates that using idealized reductions to prove security of signature schemes can backfire as schemes can have properties that the idealized scenario does not consider. My gripe was that I did not understand where a postulate in section 4.2 comes from but afer kelalaka pointed me in the right direction it clicked.